# How can I verify the backup password for an iOS device?

Tags: ios, itunes, backup, password, encryption

In iTunes, my iPad shows itself as backing up to "This Computer", and the "Encrypt Local Backup" button is checked. I believe I know the password, but I would like to be sure. How can I verify that the password I believe to be correct is in fact correct, without changing it?

I'd like to avoid changing it because then I need to change it temporarily to something else, and then change it back. But after doing that, I'm left in the same situation of not being 100% sure that I haven't accidentally made a mistake and not reset the password to what it was originally.

Comment: Write the password into TextEdit, copy/paste it into all three fields of the "change password" dialog, live happily ever after :-)

Comment: Unless some clever engineer wrote `if ((new == new2) && (old == new)) return;`, since, after all, you didn't ask to change anything.

Comment: Though I suppose you could test for that by setting all three to something you know isn't your password. As long as that returns an "invalid password" type error, then that is sufficient to know that the above nonsense cannot be happening.

Comment: Why don‘t you just try?

Comment: @nohillside - I did. Confidence is now higher.